# Error in react while importing the function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I am facing the compile-time error on this

```
import createProfile from "../../actions/profileActions";
```

error is following
Failed to compile.

```
[1]
[1] ./src/components/create-profile/CreateProfile.js
[1] 424:57-70 "export 'default' (imported as 'createProfile') was not found in '../../actions/profileActions
```

but the function being imported are available in profileActions.js

```
export const createProfile = (profileData, history) => dispatch => {
  axios
    .post("/api/profile", profileData)
    .then(res => history.push("/dashboard"))
    .catch(err =>
      dispatch({
        type: GET_ERRORS,
        payload: err.response.data
      })
    );
};
```

Comment: try use curly brackets: import { createProfile } from "../../actions/profileActions";

Answer (score 3):

Yes the mistakes done by first time learners of React.

To use a function defined in other file you

1.Export the function from the file it is defined.
2.Import the function in the new file.

It can be done in two ways.

**Syntax 1:**

```
export function someFunction(){}
export const constant1="ABC"
```

Use the above syntax when then are multiple functions/constants you want to export.

In this case if you want to import then follow this syntax.

```
import {function1,constant1,...} from <file-name>
```

**Syntax 2:**

Default exports works only one per file.i.e,you can't export two functions/constants the default way

```
export default function1=()=>{}//okay!!

export default function1=()=>{};
export default const someconstant;//ERROR !!
```

You can import now like this.

```
import function1 from <file-name>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need either to import `createProfile`  a single import

```
import {createProfile} from "../../actions/profileActions";
```

or export it as the default export

```
export default createProfile
```

Answer (score 1):

import createProfile as `import {createProfile} from "../../actions/profileActions";` other wise export it as

```
const createProfile = (profileData, history) => dispatch => {
  axios
    .post("/api/profile", profileData)
    .then(res => history.push("/dashboard"))
    .catch(err =>
      dispatch({
        type: GET_ERRORS,
        payload: err.response.data
      })
    );
};
export default createProfile;
```